# I have an issue in Angular Directive and Angular Routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Folder structure is as follows

assets
...........img
...........fonts
...........js
...........css
data
...........data.json
partials
...........main.html
...........contact.html
...........demo.html
...........line-of-business.html
...........product.html
directives
...........nav.html
index.html

The First Snippet is my Angular **app.js** File

The Second Snippet is my **index.html**

The Third Snippet is my **main.html** which is the partial i need to be put when the home page is loaded, similar to this one I have partials for other pages in my website

The Fourth Snippet is my **nav** custom directive which is placed inside all partials because each partial have a different id in the header

the fifth snippet is the json file I take data from to the partials

The Problem is that the directive is not loading in any of the partials html

```js
var rootCave = angular.module("rootCave", ['ngRoute']);
rootCave.directive('navigation', [

    function() {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: 'directives/nav.html'
        };
    }
]);
rootCave.service('aboutService', function($http, $q) {
    "use strict";
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('data/data.json').then(function(rcdata) {
        deferred.resolve(rcdata);
    });
    this.getAbout = function() {
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});

rootCave.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope, aboutService) {
    'use strict';
    var promise = aboutService.getAbout();
    promise.then(function(rcdata) {
        $scope.about = rcdata.data.about;
        $scope.products = rcdata.data.products;
        $scope.mobileProduct = rcdata.data.mobileProduct;
        $scope.clients = rcdata.data.clients;
        $scope.anytime = rcdata.data.anytime;
        $scope.lobProduct = rcdata.data.lobProduct;
        $scope.Product = rcdata.data.lobProduct.projectsdetails;
    });
});




rootCave.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        'use strict';
        $routeProvider.
        when('/main', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/contact.html',
                controller: 'ContactCtrl'
            })
            .when('/demo', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/demo.html',
                controller: 'DemoCtrl'
            })
            .when('/line-of-business', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/line-of-business.html',
                controller: 'LOBCtrl'
            })
            .when('/mob-app', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/mob-app.html',
                controller: 'MobAppCtrl'
            })
            .when('/mobile-apps', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/mobile-apps.html',
                controller: 'MobileAppsCtrl'
            })
            .when('/product', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/product.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/main'
        })
    }
]);
rootCave.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        'use strict';
    }
]);
rootCave.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        'use strict';
    }
]);
rootCave.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        'use strict';
    }
]);
rootCave.controller('LOBCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        'use strict';
    }
]);
rootCave.controller('MobAppCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        'use strict';
    }
]);
rootCave.controller('MobileAppsCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        'use strict';
    }
]);
rootCave.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        'use strict';
    }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="rootCave">


    <head>
        <!-- meta tags -->
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- meta tags -->

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!---- title ---->
        <title>RootCave| Software House</title>
        <!---- title ---->

        <!---- syles ---->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/flaticon/flaticon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">
        <!---- syles ---->

    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="aboutCtrl">


<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<!-- Footer Start-->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="footer-box white">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $img; ?>Logo_white.png">
                        <ul class="social">
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/rootcave"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/rootcave_team"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/root-cave"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="copy">
                           <br>
                            <p>Copyright @ 2015 - RootCave</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="footer-box white">
                        <h3 class="upper" style="
    margin-left: 45px;" >Reach Us </h3>
                        <ul class="details">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>6 Gamal Salem St., from Mosadak St., Dokki, Egypt.</li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+(20)100 5399 170</li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>info@rootcave.com</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
<!-- JavaScript Files -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- angular js -->
    <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/typeit.min.js"></script>
    <!-- smoth scroll -->
    <script src="assets/js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <!-- GOOGLE MAP -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

        function init() {
            // Basic options for a simple Google Map
            // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
            var mapOptions = {
                // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                zoom: 8,

                // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.9773051,31.3105241), // New York

                // How you would like to style the map.
                // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.

            };

            // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map
            // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('googleMap');

            // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

            // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.9773051,31.3105241),
                map: map,
                title: 'Snazzy!'
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(".nav li a").click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(window).load(
            function () {
                $(".loading").fadeOut(2000, function () {
                    $(this).parent().fadeOut(2000);
                });
            }
        );

        /*--
            auto typing plugin
        --*/
        $('.typing').typeIt({
            strings: [
                "Tailored to suit your business ",
                "Cloud based Software for your business",
                "Real time Analytics for data driven business decisions"
            ],
            speed: 150,
            breakLines: false,
            loop: true,
            cursor: false
        });
    </script>

    <!-- JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
<!-- Footer End-->

    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- Header Start ---->
<header class="header" id="header">
    <!-- navigation Start -->
<navigation></navigation>
    <!-- navigation End -->
    <div class="p-overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="header-cont">
                    <h2 class="typing" style="color: white;"></h2>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="demo.php">Get Started</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div style="padding:25% 0">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/mockups/responsive1.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Header ---->


<section class="aboutme padding white" id=aboutUs>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="text-center">Root Cave at a glance</h1>

            <p class="text-center" style="width:60%; margin: auto;">
                Root Cave delivers a business application suite for small and medium size companies around the world. , our flexible solutions help you accelerate your business growth. That flexibility allows you to choose to implement the suite on your existing servers or move to a modern cloud implementation. Explore these pages to see why we are now the fastest growing business management solution!
            </p>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="items in about track by $index" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
            <div class="col-sm-6"
               ng-repeat="i in [$index, $index + 1]"
               ng-if="about[i]"
              >
                <div class="about-box">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <i class="{{about[i].icon}}"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <h3>
                            {{about[i].title}}
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            {{about[i].description}}
                        </p>
                    </div
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="green-l padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="l-box">
                    <h3 class="white">Web App</h3>
                    <p class="white">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, perfecto accusata ad qui, amet adhuc everti ut pri. Recusabo periculis patrioque an duo. Suas alienum eos at, at nibh soleat nostrud mel. Eu eam alii sanctus sadipscing, eos nusquam voluptaria et, nominati volutpat maiestatis has ei.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, perfecto accusata ad qui, amet adhuc everti ut pri. Recusabo periculis patrioque an duo. Suas alienum eos at, at nibh soleat nostrud mel. Eu eam alii sanctus sadipscing, eos nusquam voluptaria et, nominati volutpat maiestatis has ei.
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/line-of-business">Get Started</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="l-box">
                    <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="assets/img/PcColl.png">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="mobile padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h3>Mobile App</h3>
                <p>
                    Mobile devices are increasingly utilized to access content and interact with brands. So, it is critical that you have a well-designed and solidly executed mobile experience. Root Cave provides clients with brand consistency through and throughout customized mobile websites and applications.
                </p>
                <a href="/mobile-apps" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class='clients padding text-center' id="customers">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" >
       <!-- <h1 class="text-center">Customers</h1> -->
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="client in clients track by $index" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0">
            <div class="col-sm-3"   ng-repeat="i in [$index,$index +1,$index + 2 , $index + 3]" 
               ng-if="clients[i]">
                <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="assets/img/clients/{{clients[i].clientLogo}} " >
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```html
<!-- navigation Start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Brand" src="assets/img/Logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#/main">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutUs">about us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#/line-of-business">Line Of Business App</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/mobile-apps">Mobile App</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

                <li><a href="#customers">customers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/contact">contact us</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="font-size: 35px;color:#696969;margin-top: 15px;">|</li>
                <li><a href="#/demo" class="btn btn-primary">Demo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- navigation End -->
```

Comment: That is a **lot** of code to wade through. At first glance you have syntax errors like 'use stric' and 'use script'. Can you boil this down to one small and simple example demonstrating the issue you are having? You're much more likely to get an answer if you can do that.

Comment: Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as having your directive restricted to attribute:

```
rootCave.directive('navigation', [

    function() {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: "A", <-- here you are restricting your directive to attribute
            templateUrl: 'directives/nav.html'
        };
    }
]);
```

And you are using it as an element:

```
<!-- navigation Start -->
    <navigation></navigation> <-- here you are using it as an element
<!-- navigation End -->
```

Comment: thank you lex but that was a mistake while copying , it's E and It's still not working